# How to check if generator has at least N elements

Tags: python, generator

Python doesn't provide `len()` on generators. What is most efficient way to check if generator contains at least N elements.

Some test cases:

```
>>> iter_len_at_least(range(3), 3) 
True
>>> iter_len_at_least(range(3), 4)
False
```

My naive implementation:

```
import itertools

def iter_len_at_least(i, n):
    return len(list(None for x in itertools.islice(i, 0, n))) == n
```

Is there any more pythonic way to do this check?

Comment: Note that `itertools.islive()` will chomp up the first n entries from the input iterator. (Also note that `range()` does not return an iterator but a range object since python 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the iterator with `range(n)` and then iterate and count the elements:

```
def iter_len_at_least(i, n):
    return sum(1 for _ in zip(range(n), i)) == n
```

---

Keep in mind that this will consume the next `n` elements of the iterator:

```
it = iter(range(5))
iter_len_at_least(it, 3)
print(list(it))
# output: [3, 4]
```

There's no way to avoid this, but we can split the iterator into two with [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and return one of the new iterators along with the result:

```
def iter_len_at_least(i, n):
    i, it = itertools.tee(i)
    return it, sum(1 for _ in zip(range(n), i)) == n
```

```
it = iter(range(5))
it, result = iter_len_at_least(it, 3)
print(result)
print(list(it))
# output:
# True
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```